# Java RegEx for Tab separated file with tab in the columns

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a tsv which has fileds spearated by tab but individual column is bounded by "" which could contain tab characters in it.
for example

```
  String toBeparsed= "'a1'\t'a2'\t'a3\t'\t'a4'";
```

so when i try to do

```
  String [] arr =  toBeparsed.split("\\t");
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

the output is

```
  ['a1', 'a2', 'a3, ', 'a4']
```

which is not what i expect . this should be

```
  ['a1', 'a2', 'a3\t', 'a4' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String regex="(?<=')\\t(?=')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way..

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String toBeparsed= "'a1'\t'a2'\t'a3\t'\t'a4'";
    String str[] = toBeparsed.split("'");

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
    for(String s : str){
        if(s.equals("\\t")|| s.trim().isEmpty())
        {
          continue; 
        }
            System.out.println(s+"...");
    }
}
```

O / P :

```
[, a1,  , a2,   , a3    ,   , a4]
a1...
a2...
a3  ...   \\ yes \t is here
a4...
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead, with the `+` after:

```
String [] arr =  toBeparsed.split("\\t+");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: Returns the same result i.e  ['a1', 'a2', 'a3, ', 'a4'] instead of 
['a1', 'a2', 'a3\t', 'a4' ] even with toBeparsed.split("\\t+");

Comment: Oh, I see. Is your example output correct? I would expect something like `['a1', 'a2', 'a3', '', 'a4']`

Comment: yes my example output is correct i want to retain "\t" when its inside the string i mean quotes

Comment: yes think as if this a3 is a column from DB which might contain tabs,  which might ruin my parsing, hence those need to be retained and the output by program should be   ['a1', 'a2', 'a3\t', 'a4' ]